# Add row-wise accuracy to a seaborn heatmap

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

```py
import seaborn as sb
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

A = np.array([[10, 5], [3, 10]], dtype=np.int32)
plt.figure()
sb.heatmap(
        A,
        square=True,
        annot=True,
        xticklabels=["False", "Positive"],
        yticklabels=["False", "Positive"],
        cbar=False,
        fmt="2d",
)
plt.title("Example plot")
plt.show()
```

Shows example of an heatmap. I wish to add accuracy of each row to left side of the image.

The plot should be similar to

[image]

Can this be achived?

Comment: Since `seaborn` is based on `matplotlib` you can look into [matplotlib.pyplot.text](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.text.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the following lines to you code between the `heatmap` call and `plt.title(...`:

```py
# Compute the values to added to the plot
row_accuracies = [A[i][i] * 100 / A[i].sum() for i in range(A.shape[0])]

# Get axes
ax = fig.axes

# [OPTIONAL] Add ticks on the right side
ax.tick_params(axis='y', which='major', left=True, right=True, labelleft=True, labelright=False)

# Add text where the ticks are (roughly)
for i, acc in enumerate(row_accuracies):
    ax.text(ax.get_xlim()[1] * 1.05, ax.get_yticks()[i] * 1.01, f'{acc:.2f}%')
```

This is the result:

[image]